# Weird texture bug not going away

Tags: sculpting

So I've had this issue randomly happen before and I would just tab out and back into sculpt mode and it would fix the issue, but this time it doesn't. Any ideas how to fix this?

Note: I am a beginner at sculpting, so I wasn't messing with anything other than sculpting.

[image]

Comment: Flipped faces, maybe? In edit mode try selecting the whole mesh, then from the options at the top of the viewport, pick `mesh > normals > recalculate outside`. Although, that won't help if it's a genuine "glitch".

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work :(

Comment: Yeah, I don't know then. If it's happening inconsistently (fixed by a tab switch) it does seem more like some kind of "glitch" than a problem with your mesh. Do you experience any other graphical glitches? Maybe try updating your graphics drivers?

Comment: I have had these issues also at times and have just had the same answer of "your drivers are not up to date" which is potentially the case for some but says that older computers are being forced to be "outdated" by Blender themselves.  Pot luck.  They fix some things but mostly keep adding features and don't fix glitches as they go along because theyre too busy adding new features all the time. It's annoying.

Comment: Ahh. My pc is a new build with up to date drivers :(